# Odata - How to filter on collection property of type enum

Tags: c#, odata, azure-cosmosdb

I'm attempting to filter my entities on a property which is a collection of `enum` variants.
If the collection contains the variant I'm interested in, I want to return that entity.

My backing store is Cosmos DB and currently I'm storing the `enum` variants as an `array` of `string` (I'm not tied to that).

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(JsonStringEnumConverter))]
public enum FsmoRole 
{
    RidMaster,
    PdcEmulator,
    // Other FSMO roles
}

public class DomainController
{
    public IList<FsmoRole> FsmoRole { get; set; } =
        new List<FsmoRole>():
}
```

The query I was attempting to execute was the following:

> $filter=fsmoRoles/any(f: f eq RidMaster)

This returns the following error from the Odata API:

> Microsoft.OData.ODataException: Could not find a property named 'RidMaster' on type 'DomainController'

And, if I use quotes around the variant I'm interested I get back no results:

> $filter=fsmoRoles/any(f: f eq 'RidMaster')

One solution I could use instead is to use a collection of `string`'s to represent the FSMO roles. This would allow me to do the following:

> $filter=fsmoRoles/any(f:contains(f, 'RidMaster'))

And this works and is a viable option, but I wanted to know if I could perform this query without having to change the entities `FsmoRoles` property to a collection of `string`'s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is, you're storing the `enum` variants as `string`'s in the backing store.

If you look at the generated `Expression` tree, you'll see that it's converting your input values to `Int32` and then attempting the comparison in the DB.

```
.Where($it => $it.FsmoRoles.Any(f => (Convert(f, Int32) == 2)))
```

Last time I checked the value `2` is not equal to `"RidMaster"`. This is why you're not seeing results.
I would stop storing the collection of `FsmoRoles` as `string`'s and instead store them as `int`'s.

When returning the results from your controller you can serialize the `enum` variants to `string`.

Another option (if you don't want to store the `FsmoRoles` as `int`'s) is to use the `cast` operator.

Your query would then look something like this:

> $filter=fsmoRoles/any(f: cast(f, Edm.String) eq 'RidMaster')